# Cannot resolve method 'get' in 'Object' using streams

Tags: java

`items` is a `List<List<String>>`. When I add `reversed`, I see a compile error `Cannot resolve method 'get' in 'Object'`. I get this on `x.get(0)`. Why do I get this and how can I get the reverse order? I would just like to sort the list based on the item name.

```
    List<List<String>> items = new ArrayList<>();
 List<String> item2 = new ArrayList<>();
        item2.add("item2");
        item2.add("3");
        item2.add("4");
        List<String> item1 = new ArrayList<>();
        item1.add("item1");
        item1.add("10");
        item1.add("15");
        List<String> item3 = new ArrayList<>();
        item3.add("item3");
        item3.add("17");
        item3.add("8");
        items.add(item1);
        items.add(item2);
        items.add(item3);

items.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.get(0)).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: What if you use `Comparator.<List<String>>comparing(x->x.get(0))`?

Comment: I get `Wrong number of type arguments: 1; required: 2`

Comment: My fault. It should be `Comparator.<List<String>, String>comparing(x->x.get(0))`. Alternatively, you could try `Comparator.comparing((List<String> x)->x.get(0))`.

Comment: yes it works, but can u let me know why?

Comment: @user3310115 Loosely speaking, in @dan1st's comment, `Comparator.<List<String>, String>comparing(x->x.get(0))`, the first `List<String>` refers to the element type your stream uses, and the second `String` is what's actually getting compared (since you take the first `String` from each `List<String` and compare them)

Comment: but what is the need to specify it? Why doesn't the compiler know that its a List<String>. If it was an object, I don't need to specify it right? Like I could just use `Employee::getFirstName` or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's type inference fails here. When running `Comparator.comparing(x -> x.get(0)).reversed()`, it is not able to infer the types of the `Comparator` from the return type because of the `.reversed()`. Since they cannot be inferred, Java just uses `Object`.

In order to fix that, you need to somehow specify the type that is compared.

This can be done explicitly with `Comparator.<List<String>, String>> comparing(x->x.get(0)).reversed()`. Here, `List<String>, String>` are type arguments for the `Comparator.comparing` call. This means they specify the values of the generic types at compile-time so they don't have to be inferred. The first type parameter (`List<String>`) is the type to compare and second parameter (`String`) is the `Comparable` that is extracted from the type to compare (the result of `List#get`).

Alternatively, you could also specify it in the lambda expression's parameters and let Java infer it from that: `Comparator.comparing((List<String> x) -> x.get(0)).reversed()`. Since Java knows that `x` is of the type `List<String>`, it is able to infer the type of the lambda (`Function<List<String>,String>`) and the `Comparator.comparing` method.

When [Sequenced Collections](https://openjdk.org/jeps/8280836) are added to Java, you could also use use method references. If you use `Comparator.comparing(List::getFirst).reversed()`, Java knows that the type to compare is a `List` and is able to use the `get` method. Note that `List::getFirst` is not yet part of the JDK as of the time of writing this.

As [@Slaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6395627/slaw) [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73315726/cannot-resolve-method-get-in-object-using-streams/73315918?noredirect=1#comment129477002_73315918), you could also use an entirely different approach by getting rid of the `.reversed` and including it in the `Comparator.comparing` like this: `Comparator.comparing(x -> x.get(0), Comparator.reverseOrder())`. The [second parameter is another `Comparator` that is used for comparing the values extracted from the lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function,java.util.Comparator)) `x -> x.get(0)`.

Comment: `Comparator.comparing(x -> x.get(0), Comparator.reverseOrder())` is another option, which can be made less verbose by statically importing `comparing` and/or `reverseOrder`

Answer (score 0):

```java
List<List<String>> sorted_list = items.stream()
          .sorted(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.get(0), Comparator.reverseOrder()))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: sorry for that, I'm new to this site, I'll try to post next time onwords. I wrote this code for sorting reverse order `[[item3, 17, 8], [item2, 3, 4], [item1, 10, 15]]` this will be the output